# What's the proper greedy algorithm approaching "Job shop scheduling" problem?

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, greedy

having N jobs of different size with specific dependencies (of other Jobs) defined, what's a good greedy approach to assign these Jobs to M Machines with various processing power?

first, I came up with the idea of defining different levels such that works with no dependency come as the first level and level of the other job's nodes in the graph being the longest path from the level one nodes to those nodes.
then assigning the heaviest job in each level to the most powerful machine and following the order, but then I thought maybe how many jobs depend on current jobs is a more important factor.

Comment: Putting the jobs on different levels is known as a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).